# submit button refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm working on a footer generator.
Which looks like this: 
[image]

This "preview" button has 2 functions function 1 is posting the values that the user entered in the black box like this :

[image]

and the second function is to show me a button(which is hidden by default with css) called "button-form-control-generate" with jquery like this:

```
$("button.form-control").click(function(event){
    $("button.form-control-generate").show();
});
```

Now here comes my problem:

If i click on preview it refreshes the page.. so if i click on preview it shows the hidden button for like 1 second then it refreshes the page and the button goes back to hidden. So i tried removing the `type="submit"` but if i do that it wont post the entered data like it did in image 2 it will show the hidden button though, but because the submit type is gone it wont post the entered data on the black box.

Here is my code:

```
<form class ="form" method="post">

            <h3>Select your trademark</h3>

                <select class="form-control" name="trademark" action="">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>©</option>
                    <option>™</option>
                    <option>®</option>
                </select>

            <h3>Your company name</h3>

            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="companyName" placeholder="Your company name" />

                <br/>
                <br/>

            <button class="form-control" type= "submit" name="submit">
                Preview
            </button>
            <br/>
            <button class="form-control-generate"name= "submit">
                Generate
            </button>
        </form>




<!-- script for the preview image -->

        <div id = "output">
        <?php

        function footerPreview ()
        {
            date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

            $trademark = $_POST["trademark"];

            $company = $_POST["companyName"];

            $date = date("Y");

            echo "<div id='footer_date'>$trademark $date $company </div>";
        }

        footerPreview();

        ?>
```

The jquery:

```
$("button.form-control").click(function(event){
    $("button.form-control-generate").show();
});
```

Already tried prevent default but if i do this the users entered data doesnt show in the preview box. Looks like preventdefault stops this bit from working:

```
<!-- script for the preview image -->

        <div id = "output">
        <?php

        function footerPreview ()
        {
            date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

            $trademark = $_POST["trademark"];

            $company = $_POST["companyName"];

            $date = date("Y");

            echo "<div id='footer_date'>$trademark $date $company </div>";
        }

        footerPreview();

        ?>
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` inside your click function will disallow the page refresh on submission.

Comment: If this is just to preview the footer do you need to submit the form at all, could you not just use JS to collect the selected options and print then into a div on a button click instead of submitting a form?

Comment: if i use prevent default it doesnt shoe the user entered data in the preview box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to post the form you can use the `preventDefault();` function.

```js
$("button.form-control").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("button.form-control-generate").show();
});
```

Comment: For some reason if i do that it doesn't post the entered data in the footer preview box

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button.form-control").click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 setTimeout(function(){$("button.form-control-generate").show();},100);
 });
```

Try It Once

Answer (score 0):

Submit your form as

```
$('.form').on('submit', function(e){
    $("button.form-control-generate").show();
    e.preventDefault();
    this.submit();
})
```

instead of using the click event. With button of type submit the submit() action is triggered automatically so you can show your button in the submit handler and then prevent the default action to refresh the page.

UPDATE:

Instead of using php you can do the same with jquery as well.

```js
$('.form').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   var date = new Date();
   date = date.getYear() + 1900;
   var data = $(this).serializeArray();
 
  var str = data[0].value + date + data[1].value;
  $('#output').text(str);
  $('.form-control-generate').show();
})
```

```css
.form-control-generate {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class ="form" method="post">

            <h3>Select your trademark</h3>

                <select class="form-control" name="trademark" action="">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>©</option>
                    <option>™</option>
                    <option>®</option>
                </select>

            <h3>Your company name</h3>

            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="companyName" placeholder="Your company name" />

                <br/>
                <br/>

            <button class="form-control" type= "submit" name="submit">
                Preview
            </button>
            <br/>
            <button class="form-control-generate" name= "submit">
                Generate
            </button>
        </form>




<!-- script for the preview image -->

        <div id = "output"></div>
```

Comment: Tried it but this but if i do so it stops showing me the entered data in the preview box.

Comment: try return false instead of e.preventDefault();

Comment: Looks like e.preventDefault() prevents the form from submitting try the update. I think i should work

Comment: Isnt it a posibility to achieve this using ajax, i just don't know how

Answer (score 0):

@ShubhamKhatri almost had it right

The problem is, he thought this was an on submit event, I don't believe it should be. I believe you have the type="submit" on the wrong button. Surely `preview` wouldn't submit the form? You want to submit on `generate`, no?

so a slight change to the markup - added an id to preview to make life simple

```
<button class="form-control" id="preview">
    Preview
</button>
<br/>
<button class="form-control-generate" type="submit" name="submit">
    Generate
</button>
```

and a slight modification to the code in @ShubhamKhatri answer

```
$("#preview").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var date = new Date();
    date = date.getYear() + 1900;
    var data = $('.form').serializeArray();

    var str = data[0].value + ' ' + date + ' ' + data[1].value;
    $('#footer_date').text(str);
    $('.form-control-generate').show();
});
```

et voilà